# Loading initial text, into CKEditor

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I have integrated CKEditor to my django app, I am able to save the text to my database easily. But i cant find a way to Edit that data. I am unable to find a way to load the text into ckeditor.

models.py

```
class BlogContent(models.Model):
    emailID = models.EmailField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    blogID = UUIDField(auto=True)
    blogHead = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blogBody = RichTextField()
    blogDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

form.py

```
class addBlog(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = BlogContent
        fields = ['blogHead', 'blogBody']
        widget = {'blogBody': CKEditorWidget()}
```

view.py

```
def addNewArticle(request):
    form = addBlog()
    args = {"form": form}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("addNewArticle.html", args)
```

How do i accomplish that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just instance the Form with a hash inside, that hash must have the next structure:

```
{"field_name": "value"}
```

so just change this line:

```
 form = addBlog()
```

for this one:

```
 form = addBlog({"blogBody": "valueFromDatabase"})
```

This can works with either `ModelForm` or `Forms`, but with `ModelForms` you can also pass an instance from The Model that the ModelForm uses, so this will also works.

```
 instance = BlogContent.objects.get(id=1)
 form = addBlog(instance=instance)
```